# Working with blocks?

Tags: ios, iphone, int, block

In an interview I recently attented I was asked to predict the output of a code segment. Even if I got it right, I was not able to explain how got it.
This is the code segment.

```
int num =2;
int (^ myblock)(void)=^{
    return num*5;
};

NSLog(@"my block  call 1  %d",myblock());
num = 5;
NSLog(@"my block  call 2  %d",myblock());
```

Can anybody explain why the answer is 10 both times.?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The num variable gets copied within the block if not marked with __block. This means that the external scope num and the inner num are actually kept at different addresses in memory and changing one doesn't affect the other. To force the compiler to use the same address, mark the variable with __block

Comment: And the only actual *explanation*.

Answer (score 1):

The variable outside the block can't be changed except add '__block' before it. So the num always equal 2.

```
 __block int num =2;
```

Then you will get 10 and 25

Answer (score 1):

Add __block keyword before declaration so you can access the variable inside the block.

```
 __block int num =2;
    int (^ myblock)(void)=^{
        return num*5;
    };

    NSLog(@"my block  call 1  %d",myblock());
    num = 5;
    NSLog(@"my block  call 2  %d",myblock());
```

Try this...

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan Hodson says in his [tutorial on Objective-C Blocks:](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/blocks)

> Non-local variables are copied and stored with the block as const
>   variables, which means they are read-only. Trying to assign a new
>   value to the make variable from inside the block will throw a compiler
>   error.

`num` is defined as a non-local variable.

> The fact that non-local variables are copied as constants means that a
>   block doesn’t just have access to non-local variables—it creates a
>   snapshot of them. Non-local variables are frozen at whatever value
>   they contain when the block is defined, and the block always uses that
>   value, even if the non-local variable changes later on in the program.

If you want to reflect new value of `num` in block declare num as block variable

```
__block int num =2;  // *** Declared as block variable, value change will effect inside block  ***
```

Lets understand it with your example only.

**Non-local(Non block) variable***

```
int num =2;
int (^ myblock)(void)=^{
    return num*5;
};

NSLog(@"my block  call 1  %d",myblock());
num = 5;
NSLog(@"my block  call 2  %d",myblock());
```

**Result :**

my block  call 1  10

my block  call 2  10

**block variable***

```
__block int num =2;
int (^ myblock)(void)=^{
    return num*5;
};

NSLog(@"my block  call 1  %d",myblock());
num = 5;
NSLog(@"my block  call 2  %d",myblock());
```

**Result :**

my block  call 1  10

my block  call 2  25

Comment: You can't just copy and paste whole paragraphs from a blog, and only provide a link at the bottom as a reference. [You should make it explicit that you're quoting another work](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) by using block quotes – and giving credit to the author.

Comment: Lots of people use's other's work without mentioning, I already mentioned that its referenced from blog. Though i have added at top.

Comment: "Lots of people us[ing] other's work without mentioning" is no excuse to do it yourself. As a high(er) rep user, you should try and set an example.

Comment: @originaluser relevant username

Comment: @ValentinRadu haha ;)